# How do i open a fragment from an onClickListener inside a fragment in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am very new to Kotlin, and i am studying it at school at the moment. 
So the deal is that i have 3 tabs, that is supposed to contain stuff. Once i click "add" in one of the tabs, i want to open a new window to enter some information to save. I've been trying to use the fragment i'm on to create a new fragment, containing a very simple input field.

If anyone could tell me where i need to place my onClickListener and what to type in order to make it work, i'd be very thankful.

Any tips for refactoring my code in order to make it more readable for a newbie would be welcome also.

(DISCLAIMER: As it stands now, the app will crash due to "Unable to find explicit activity class ..."
I've fiddled a bit in the manifest to fix it, but to no avail. It feels wrong if the issue is there.)

**Frag1.kt**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_frag1.view.*


class Frag1 : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false)

        view.btnAddPerson.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().startActivity(
                Intent(requireActivity(), RegisterPersonFrag::class.java)
            )
        }
        return view
    }

}
```

**fragment_frag1.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Frag1">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAddPerson"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.825"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.896"
        app:rippleColor="#FFFFFF" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RegisterPersonFrag.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class RegisterPersonFrag : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_person, container, false)
    }


}
```

**fragment_register_person.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterPersonFrag">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.161">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import MyAdapter
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var tabLayout: TabLayout? = null
    var viewPager: ViewPager? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabs)
        viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager)

        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("UPCOMING"))
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("PAST"))
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("GIFTS TO BUY"))
        tabLayout!!.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL

        val adapter = MyAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager, tabLayout!!.tabCount)
        viewPager!!.adapter = adapter


        viewPager!!.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))

        tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                viewPager!!.currentItem = tab.position
            }
            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tip for you :

 Do not use `!!` operator, it's code smell. Instead of it you can declare your variable `tabLayout` as `lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout` so in future after it declaration  `tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabs)` you can have access without any conversion from nullable to non-nullable.

According to your question if you want to open new activity via `Intent` the second paramert should be `Activity` , not a `Fragment` (your class RegisterPersonFrag.kt is Fragment)! So here you have two way :

1. Create new `Activity` and call it like you do.
2. Read about `fragmentManager` and `replace` or `add` your fragment in particular container.

Comment: This was a perfect answer! Thank you very much!